# Why I can't generate a signed apk file in Android Studio?

Tags: export, android-studio

I would like to generate an apk file from my project, but the *Generate Signed APK...* option in Android Studio looks like it's disabled. So what should I do next?

[image]

Comment: You need a certificate so do you have one?  Why are you tryin to sign a decompiled project?

Comment: Becouse the softver is brocken and I trying to fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

Change the Build variant from debug to Release!

Comment: Can you explain in detail how the OP should do this?

Answer (score 0):

Follow Below Steps for Nice and Easy Way:-

Go to Tools->Flutter->Open for editing in android studio.

Choose separate window. This will open the android part of your project in separate window.

Wait to Gradle to finish it's build.

Go to Build-> Generate signed bundle/apk.

Follow below video for further process.

https://youtu.be/MjpaSGEmQHs

Thank me later..!